# Найти из двух чисел меньшее и положить это число в массив через ifelse

Tags: c++

Есть задача которую нужно решить через ifelse: ***Наша задача - из двух чисел выбрать меньшее. Будут даны несколько пар чисел для более тщательной проверки.
Входные данные - в первой строке указано количество пар сравниваемых чисел.
Следующие строки содержат сами эти пары - по одной на строку.
Ответ должен содержать наименьшие элементы из каждой пары, через пробел.*** 
 У меня код, который работает не совсем так как мне нужно, но я пытаюсь отталкиваться от него. Я не могу понять как мне выбрать наименьшее число из пары и положить его в массив(я буду складывать все это в ans). Когда я пытаюсь логически построить работу ifelse то вскипает голова, тк мой метод полностью не работает.

```
int main()
{
const int nMax = 100;
int n;
int arr[nMax][2];
int ans;

cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> arr[nMax][0];
    cin >> arr[nMax][1];
    }
    if (arr[nMax][0] > arr[nMax][1]) {
        cout << "1" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "2" << endl;
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

вот данные значения

 23 
8516014 -596228

1538434 -3119764
8791417 -830044

 3798697 -9778508 
5034308 2778176

 -1854099 7906581 
-4888489 5988698

 -951713 2141320 
-6257220 -568126

 -960296 -907355 
8661697 -2989094

 -2171432 -8422782 
8625801 4861642

 3017681 1788673 
-457165 1097998

 -4410089 -7613947 
1424116 3015186

 -8623024 -8801749 
7930742 1949350

 3838003 5679022 
4952621 -8941242

 -4459424 -3883945
9259456 -6590945

Comment: Не нужен никакой массив. Считали `n`, просто в цикле - читаете 2 числа, сравниваете их, выводите меньшее **число** (не 1 или 2!) и пробел. Все! Никакой массив вообще не нужен.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/13o1cfe в гифке к задачи показано, что я после сравнения ложу меньшее число в массив. Мне нужно все наименьшие числа будет вывести одним ответом, а не выводить после каждого сравнения наименьшее, как у меня сейчас это делается

Comment: а зачем ты печатаешь "1" или "два", когда надо напечатать одно из двух данных чисел?

Comment: я хочу поместить меньшее число в массив, но не знаю как, и меньшее число тоже не понимаю как вывести, так что вывел 1 или 2 для проверки работоспособности

Comment: Так, задачка явно из какого-то онлайн-курса. Дайте URL, если сами не хотите убедиться, что мой способ работает...

Comment: https://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/min-of-two Я понял про что вы говорите, мне надо сделать так  `if (arr[nMax][0] > arr[nMax][1]) {
   cout << arr[nMax][0] << endl;
  }
  else {
   cout << arr[nMax][1] << endl;
  } `

Comment: но это все равно не то, после каждого сравнения много времени уйдет копировать каждое значение, поэтому я и хочу помещать сразу их в массив, чтобы дальше его просто вывести

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не надо копировать... Не обязательно дожидаться всего ввода для начала вывода - может, это для вас и новость, но потоки ввода и вывода - различны, это просто на экране все перемешано :)

Вот такая программа вполне проходит указанный сайт и признана корректной:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int a, b, i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> a >> b;
        if (a >= b) a = b;
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }
}
```

И еще - когда вы пишете кому-то ответ в комментариях - добавляйте его имя с `@` - например, для меня - напишите `@Harry`. А то я ваш комментарий увидел чисто случайно...

Comment: Да, это работат, спасибо, но у меня сразу после сравнения опять выводит ответ https://prnt.sc/13pmjum . А зачем a = b; после if()?  @Harry

Comment: Помещаем в `a` наименьшее число. Чтоб обойтись без `else`  Можно, конечно, `if (a < b) cout << a << " "; else cout << b << " ";` Или даже `cout << (a<b?a:b)<<" Эжё

Comment: Что до вывода - вы что, все эти пары руками вводите? 8-/ Запишите в файл, скажем, `data`, и вызывайте в командной строке `prog.exe < data`. Или вы думаете, что там, на проверяющем сайте, сидит какой-то человечек и быстро-быстро вводит? :)

Comment: нет, я копирую и вставляю значения,пишу в visual studio  @Harry

Comment: if (a >= b) a = b; это значит если a больше или ровно b - тогда a присвается b? и почему это записано на одной строке @Harry

Comment: Рассмотрите разные пары чисел и посмотрите, чему будет равно `a` после этой строки - меньшему из пары чисел.